# ionic 3 login with facebook

Tags: cordova, apk, ionic3, facebook-login

I am trying to make login with facebook to my ionic 3 app, I have followed this tutorial:

https://www.djamware.com/post/59ad3a0c80aca768e4d2b135/login-with-ionic-3-and-cordova-native-facebook-connect-plugin

and followed every step he made, and after I finished I used this command to create my apk file so I can test it on mobile,

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXfuS.jpg)

Later I tried to remove `cordova-plugin-facebook4`  and run the build command again and I could make the apk successfully .

Any idea why I get the error and how to solve it and use facebook login?

Comment: Did you remove angular dependency for fb plugin using npm uninstall......  command? if possible give your project & environment detail using ionic info. Thanks

Comment: @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.9.1
    npm               : 3.10.8
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Program Files\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows

Misc:

    backend : pro

Comment: and yes when i removed facebook plugin and dependency using command , the issue will be fixed and work fine , 

but i do need to have facebook login in .

Comment: Solved when i downgrade my android version from 7.0.0 to 6.3.0
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0

Comment: Great! Happy ionic.